# Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster, rgdal

```
library(terra)
library('sp')
library(raster)
library('gimms','rgdal')
input <- "F:/BaiduSyncdisk/graduatepaper/guaduate/data"
out <- "F:/BaiduSyncdisk/graduatepaper/guaduate/area/gimms_NDVI"
fn1 <- paste0(input,"/ndvi3g_geo_v1_",2020,"_","0712",".nc4")
ndvi3g <- rasterizeGimms(x = fn1)
```

> Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
> Error in ncdf4::nc_open(filename, suppress_dimvals = TRUE) :
> Error in nc_open trying to open file F:/BaiduSyncdisk/graduatepaper/guaduate/data/ndvi3g_geo_v1_2020_0712.nc4 (return_on_error= FALSE )

I tried to change the working path, but it didn'twork.

```
getwd()
# [1] "D:/Program Files/R"
setwd("F:/BaiduSyncdisk/graduatepaper/guaduate/data")
```

Comment: What does `file.exists` return for that file name?  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files#